JavaScript Azure Functions V4 CORS error, but function still executes
I created an Azure Functions with JavaScript, V4, Node 20.
I protected it with cors for 1 origin.
When I do a request to this endpoint from another origin, I get CORS error as expected

but for some reason, the function is still executed

Why is this happening? Nothing special about my function code:
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('contact', {
    methods: ['POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        console.log('executed');
        return {
                status: 200,
                body: 'OK',
            }
    }
});


FIXED - I also manually check for a valid origin now
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('contact', {
    methods: ['POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        // manual CORS
        const origin = request.headers.get('origin');
        const allowedOrigins = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS.split(',');
        if (!origin || origin.length == 0 || !allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
            return {
                status: 403,
                body: 'Forbidden',
            }
        }

        return {
            status: 200,
            body: 'OK'
        }
    }
});


PS: env var in local.settings.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "ALLOWED_ORIGINS": "http://mywebsite.com,http:localhost:4321"
  }
}

